# Magento update - Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions

Tags: shell, magento, file-permissions, magento-1.4

I'm once again in need of your help...
I'm trying to update an existing Magento shop (currently version 1.4.1.1) to the newest version available.

I've created a development environment in which I would like to test the effects this update has on the shop. Unfortunately I'm running into some problems with the installation and I hope someone can clear things up a bit.

I'm using the tutorial I found on the internet http://duntuk.com/magento-upgrade

I'm stuck at the point where I want to run

`./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force`

At this point I always get the following error message:

```
Error: 
install: Please check for sufficient write file permissions.
Error: 
install: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.
```

I've googled for hours now and can't seem to find a solution. I've run all possible commands I know and could find to change that. I've made all directories inside the Magento folder 777 and all files 644, 666 and even 766, but nothing changes the error message.

All the folders, including the Magento folder itself, are owned by the user I use to log in to the shell. I hope that's correct... I don't know why I keep getting this error. Has anyone else had this error even after changing all the permissions and such?

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
1. find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

After, when magento is installed

```
1. find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
2. find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
3. chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
4. chmod -R o+w media
```